# Linking/compiling a program that uses boost/filesystem.hpp

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I'm trying to use the boost/filesystem library in some code that I am writing. I seem to be having a hard time getting it to compile. I'm running Debian Wheezy, and have boost version 1.49(which is what comes if you install using apt-get). I'm trying to compile an example that is available with the documentation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    std::cout << "Usage: tut1 path\n";
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << argv[1] << " " << file_size(argv[1]) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I use the following command:

```
g++ temp.cc -o temp /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.a
```

I get a number of errors such as:

```
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o): In function `boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)':
(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o): In function `boost::filesystem3::detail::directory_iterator_increment(boost::filesystem3::directory_iterator&, boost::system::error_code*)':
(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

This is probably some linking error right? Any ideas on how I could solve it?

**UPDATE #1**:
I tried running it with the -lboost_filesyste and -L /usr/lib. It gives me the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are not linking the library properly. Also, as others mentioned, `boost_filesystem` needs also `boost_system` library. Use:

```
g++ temp.cc -o temp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

Command line param `-l foo` links `libfoo.a` library. If the static library is not in default library location, use command `-L /custom/library/dir`. But I believe `/usr/lib` is automatically taken into consideration by GCC.

---

#### Edit

According to your comment below it looks like you are not compiling the file with `main()` function, or you have a typo in `main()` name. Make sure that `temp.cc` contains one and only one of these functions:

```
int main();
int main(int argc, char** argv);
```

Of course you do remember that upper/lower case matters. :)

Comment: I tried both of those options as well. It gives me /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Your compile/link command was fine, but you need to include the boost_system library as well. "undefined reference to stuff in boost::system" is the part to pay attention to.

Comment: $ g++ -o goodgrief goodgrief.cpp -I /opt/boost_1_55_0/include /opt/boost_1_55_0/lib/libboost_filesystem.a /opt/boost_1_55_0/lib/libboost_system.a
$ ./goodgrief goodgrief
goodgrief 113167

I trust you can translate from my system directories to yours.

Answer (score 3):

Boost.Filesystem uses things in Boost.System. You have to link against that, too.

The error messages that you are seeing:

```
/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o): In function 
`boost::filesystem3::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)':
(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

that's a reference to Boost.System

Add `-lboost_system` and you should be good to go (or, at least better off).

Answer (score 1):

Compile with `-lboost_filesystem`