# load/save multiple images from/in a directory - opencv c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, save, load

i want to load a lot of images (not sequential names though) from a directory. edit them and then save them in a different directory with their original names if possible.
I load them like that:

```
glob("/photos/field_new/*.jpg", fn, false);
size_t count = fn.size(); //number of jpg files in images folder
for (size_t i=0; i<count; i++)
    images.push_back(imread(fn[i]));
```

any ideas how i can save them in the directory /photos/results/ ?
and if possible with their original names?

Comment: If you can use it, I would recommend the [filesytem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) specifically the [path class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path). The only catch is that it is c++17

Comment: I would use dirent.h file and functions

Comment: Used boost. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++17 it will be easy as there is filesystem library in standard (std::filesystem). Other wise I would recomend you to get boost::filesystem which is very similar (you should be good with replacing all of std::filesystem to boost::filesystem).

To load all images from certain folder there are 2 helper functions:

```
#include <filesystem> //for boost change this to #include <boost/filesystem> and all std:: to boost::
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> 

bool isSupportedFileType(const std::filesystem::path& pathToFile, 
                         const std::vector<std::string>& extensions)
{
    auto extension = pathToFile.extension().string();
    std::transform(extension.begin(), extension.end(), extension.begin(), [](char c)
                   {
                       return static_cast<char>(std::tolower(c));
                   });

    return std::find(extensions.begin(), extensions.end(), extension) != extensions.end();
}

std::tuple<std::vector<cv::Mat>, std::vector<std::filesystem::path>> loadImages(const std::filesystem::path& path,
                                                                                const std::vector<std::string>& extensions)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> images;
    std::vector<std::filesystem::path> names;
    for (const auto& dirIt : filesystem::DirectoryIterator(path))
    {
        if (std::filesystem::is_regular_file(dirIt.path()) && isSupportedFileType(dirIt.path(), extensions))
        {
            auto mask = cv::imread(dirIt.path().string(), cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
            if (mask.data != nullptr) //there can be problem and image is not loaded
            {
                images.emplace_back(std::move(mask));
                names.emplace_back(dirIt.path().stem());
            }
        }
    }
    return {images, names};
}
```

You can use it like this (assuming C++17):

```
auto [images, names] = loadImages("/photos/field_new/", {".jpg", ".jpeg"});
```

Or (C++11)

```
auto tupleImageName = loadImages("/photos/field_new/", {".jpg", ".jpeg"});
auto images = std::get<0>(tupleImageName);
auto names = std::get<1>(tupleImageName);
```

To save you can use this function:

```
void saveImages(const std::filesystem::path& path,
                const std::vector<cv::Mat>& images, 
                const std::vector<std::filesystem::path>& names)
{
    for(auto i = 0u; i < images.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::imwrite((path / names[i]).string(), images[i]);
    }
}
```

Like this:

```
saveImages("pathToResults",images,names);
```

In this save function it would be good to perform some validation if the number of images is the same as names, otherwise there might be a problem with stepping outside vector boundary.

Comment: i think i am using c++11 so i am going with the boost::filesystem. i will try the code now. but to get it right: i paste these two functions in my program and just call the function like "auto [images, names] = loadImages("/photos/field_new/", {".jpg", ".jpeg"});" in my main? and then i have two arrays one with images one with names?

Comment: If you are using c++11 there will be difference. I will update the post. But yeah it you call this function in main it will load everything.

Comment: i get this error: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
compilation terminated. --- 
when i delete the line where i define filesystem i get this error: ‘boost’ does not name a type
 bool isSupportedFileType(const boost::filesystem::path& pathToFile,

Comment: because #include <filesystem>  is for std::filesystem if you have boost then it will be something like #include <boost/filesystem>. The isSupportedFileType is function that I posted. Are you sure linker can see it? It seems like you didn't define in before loadImages function.

Comment: still have problems with boost... i try to link the libraries but with no luck... i am using this in cmdl: g++ -g -Wall -O4 prg.cpp -o prg `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -std=c++11 -L/usr/local/lib/ -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
what am i doing wrong here...? the error i am getting is : fatal error: boost/filesystem: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: I don't use gcc but maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944753/linking-compiling-a-program-that-uses-boost-filesystem-hpp

Comment: you could also consider `<experimental/filesystem>`

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ is compatible with C, and if you are using a Unix system, you could use dirent.h (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html). It should be something like this:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    string dirname_input="dirname/input";
    string dirname_output="dirname/output";
    d=opendir(dirname_input.c_str());
    if (d){
        while ((dir=readdir(d))!=NULL){
            string filename=dir->d_name;
            if (filename.substr(filename.size() - 4)==".jpg"){
                Mat image;
                string fullpath_input=dirname_input+'/'+filename;
                string fullpath_output=dirname_output+'/'+filename;
 
                image=imread(fullpath_input,1);
                // process image 
                imwrite(fullpath_output,image);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```